# How do I loop through tab controls and test for labels?

Tags: vb.net, testing, controls, iteration

On my form I have a tabcontrol with 12 tabpages.
Each tabpage contains many labels.
72 of them hold numerical data in their `.text` property that is either `"0"`, `""`, or `"x"` where x is a numerical data value as a string.
The rest of the labels on the page are for formatting... ie `backcolor = color.black` and used as a lineshape. Those labels `.text` is `""`

Now in order for my app to function as intended, at load the form pulls in and stuffs those labels.

The following is key to understanding why I am doing this:
Labels A B C's `.textchanged` property fires off math functions and returns the result to
Labels D E F.
AND
Labels D E F's `.textchanged` property fires off math functions and returns the result to
Labels G H I.

The math is division so if all the labels aren't stuffed yet and the `.textchanged` event fires, the math will cause divide by zero errors.

So, I set a flag on every function `if iAmLoaded = true` to only fire after the form has finished stuffing the labels.

Now once the form loads, and all the values are stuffed back into the labels... I need to trigger the `.textchanged` event on every label that the `.text` property <> `"0"` or <> `""`

My idea is to iterate the value in each label that contains a value by 1 and then subtract that 1 back from it.

```
    iAmLoaded = True
    Dim i = 0

    For Each LabelOnTheForm As Label In TabControl1.TabPages(i).Controls
        'The problem is at the second iteration of the for loop, it has a button instead of a label
        'How do I design a "If" statement to test if the control I am working with is a label and not a button
        If LabelOnTheForm = Label Then '<--- produces error 'Label' is a class type and cannot be used as an expression
            If DirectCast(LabelOnTheForm, Label).Text <> "" And DirectCast(LabelOnTheForm, Label).Text <> "0" Then
                DirectCast(LabelOnTheForm, Label).Text = (Convert.ToDouble(DirectCast(LabelOnTheForm, Label).Text) + 1).ToString
                DirectCast(LabelOnTheForm, Label).Text = (Convert.ToDouble(DirectCast(LabelOnTheForm, Label).Text) - 1).ToString
                i = i + 1
            Else
                i = i + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: [IEnumerable.OfType(T)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: I'm not sure how to use this...

Comment: I say that only after reading on it and trying to implement it.
`Dim query1 As IEnumerable(Of controls) = item.OfType(Of Label)()`

Comment: that doesn't work can you help with the syntax please

Comment: _For Each lbl As Label In tab.TabPages(0).Controls.OfType(Of Label)()_

Comment: You don't need to check if you have a label. Only labels are returned by the OfType above. Of course the label should be contained in the TabPage.Controls container not in another container like a _GroupBox.Controls_ or a _Panel.Controls_

Comment: Secondary question: Why is my for loop pulling buttons at all?  Shouldn't it be only grabbing labels in the first place? I just tried to code around it with this if statement but my gut tells me ive messed up somewhere in the loop.

Comment: Something.Controls loops over all present controls. So, Groupbox1.Controls would loop over everything you put in it.

Comment: never-mind you answered both questions. it work perfectly thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Steve...
The Answer:

```
    iAmLoaded = True
    Dim i = 0

    Do While i <> 12
        For Each LabelOnTheForm As Label In TabControl1.TabPages(i).Controls.OfType(Of Label)()

            If DirectCast(LabelOnTheForm, Label).Text <> "" And DirectCast(LabelOnTheForm, Label).Text <> "0" Then
                DirectCast(LabelOnTheForm, Label).Text = (Convert.ToDouble(DirectCast(LabelOnTheForm, Label).Text) + 1).ToString
                DirectCast(LabelOnTheForm, Label).Text = (Convert.ToDouble(DirectCast(LabelOnTheForm, Label).Text) - 1).ToString
            End If

        Next

        i = i + 1

    Loop
```

Comment: You can simplify the code by declaring a variable to hold the result of DirectCast. Then use that variable in your if statement. `Dim lbl = DirectCast(LabelOnTheForm, Label)`. Then in next line `If lbl.Text <> "" And lbl.Text <> "0"` and so on.

Comment: Follow up question: is there anyway to determine the order to which the for loop in this example pulls the labels? I have successfully been able to filter out all the unwanted labels but it grabs the wrong one first and fires the text changed event

Comment: Han I like that thought

Comment: You can sort the result of OfType() based on something, like its properties. Example, sorting the labels based on their Left (location) property, `For Each LabelOnTheForm As Label In Controls.OfType(Of Label).OrderBy(Function(x) x.Left)`

Comment: nice! I'll try that!

Comment: `For Each LabelOnTheForm As Label In TabControl1.TabPages(i).Controls.OfType(Of Label).OrderBy(Function(x) x.Top)`

Did the trick!
Couldn't use `.left` but since the labels math logic is top down.. ordering by `.top` worked!

Thank you so much learning a lot today.

Answer (score 0):

Using Hans Suggestion for simplification:

```
    iAmLoaded = True
    Dim i = 0
    Dim test As String
    Do While i <> 12
        For Each LabelOnTheForm As Label In TabControl1.TabPages(i).Controls.OfType(Of Label)()
            Dim lbl = DirectCast(LabelOnTheForm, Label)
            test = NumFormat(lbl.Text)
            If test = lbl.Text And
                    lbl.Text <> "" And lbl.Text <> "0" Then
                lbl.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(lbl.Text) + 1).ToString
                lbl.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(lbl.Text) - 1).ToString
            End If

        Next
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

The problem now is I am back at square one:
Once the labels are loaded with their values... The above code will iterate and subtract one from each value to fire the `.textchanged` event however since it is pulling labels at random... it has updated one of the labels that needed data from a prior label in my logic but the for loop in the example above is pulling labels at random.
Is there a way for me to set an order for it to pull labels off the form?

Comment: `NumFormat()` function strips the labels text property of any non numerical value. Some of the labels are used as labels and they have both letters and numbers. So if it is a label that I am trying to work with, after being put through the `NumFormat()` function it will match the original string or it is a label that has been stripped and therefore not one i'm trying to work with. I'm just putting this comment here in case in the future someone is reading this code and wanted to know what that function did.